# Overflow DIV to fit exactly inside browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to set vertical scroll bar to the `div2` to replace the default browser vertical scroll bar.

```css
.div1 {
  height: 200px;
}
.div2 {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container' style="height:100%">
  <div class='div1'>
    div1 content
  </div>
  <div class='div2'>
    div2 content
  </div>
</div>
```

With the above style, document is left with blank space at the bottom since height of `div2` is not exactly occupying the entire document height. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps to achieve what you want are:

- Set both `html`'s and `body`'s `margin` and `padding` to `0`.
- Set the `header`'s height to the fixed height you want: in your case, `200px`.
- Set the `.main`'s height to 100% of the viewport less the `header` height: `calc(100vh - 200px)`.
- Set the `.main`'s `overflow-y` to `auto`.
- Create a `section` into the `.main`, and set the margin you want to show your content *(optional)*.

And then, we're done! Take a look at the example below (if you want to test it in a better way, click on the `Full Page` button, and then play with your window's resizing etc):

```css
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  height: 120px;
  background-color: blue;
}

div.main {
  height: calc(100vh - 120px);
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

div.main > section {
  margin: 10px;
}

div.main > div > p {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<header>
</header>
<div class="main">
  <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc tincidunt enim sit amet diam bibendum, ut rhoncus est molestie. Ut vulputate egestas mauris, eget ultricies tellus aliquet nec. Mauris nec neque et lorem volutpat feugiat eget sit amet
      erat. Nullam luctus ultricies augue ut cursus. Mauris pulvinar velit at venenatis semper. Quisque non dolor ante. Nulla tempus id turpis et placerat. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vestibulum justo elit, rhoncus vitae
      massa non, condimentum ornare quam. Duis sit amet orci a risus mollis gravida et quis augue. Donec sed felis ante. Vestibulum rutrum non dolor quis finibus. Vestibulum ultricies leo eget mi elementum, vel vestibulum felis maximus. Donec congue lorem
      vel ante mattis, eu luctus magna finibus. Donec sit amet dui quam.
    </p>
    <p>
      In ullamcorper, nibh eget venenatis imperdiet, augue ante porttitor mauris, nec scelerisque tortor nisi eu arcu. Phasellus libero ligula, eleifend a lobortis in, cursus in tellus. Morbi volutpat, sem a dignissim venenatis, velit nulla vehicula sem, ut
      fermentum augue eros sit amet nisi. Vivamus eget ex id turpis scelerisque lobortis sed sed arcu. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur hendrerit iaculis justo, at iaculis est facilisis sit amet. Donec sem tellus, posuere et metus id, consectetur vehicula sapien.
      Ut eros quam, tempor vitae quam sed, efficitur faucibus sapien. Mauris varius velit orci, sit amet fermentum neque auctor ac. Nullam pretium sed urna et pellentesque.
    </p>
    <p>
      Nunc id odio ligula. Sed ut dolor vitae sem fringilla condimentum. Sed venenatis lacus a magna egestas, nec volutpat quam ullamcorper. Maecenas volutpat eu magna nec ultrices. In egestas, risus id porta condimentum, odio urna ultricies mi, ut elementum
      magna tortor quis eros. Sed a hendrerit felis. Curabitur id sem consectetur, luctus velit in, sollicitudin elit. Proin ac commodo tortor. Proin imperdiet id massa at sollicitudin. Pellentesque enim arcu, venenatis ut dictum et, ornare at tortor.
      Donec et urna nec metus rhoncus auctor. Nunc id nisi nec sem condimentum vehicula a in arcu.
    </p>
    <p>
      Proin eleifend sem massa, at auctor eros porta congue. Aliquam nec aliquet justo, at cursus ipsum. Cras justo leo, varius vel accumsan eget, sagittis sit amet lorem. Donec pulvinar ante ut efficitur eleifend. Duis tincidunt metus non nunc accumsan, vel
      accumsan velit rhoncus. Nunc arcu magna, sollicitudin non urna in, pellentesque dignissim eros. Nam placerat sodales rutrum. Sed quis placerat leo. Nunc porttitor nisi nunc, in feugiat dolor accumsan nec. Aliquam gravida diam ac tempor sodales.
      Ut in sapien gravida odio molestie vehicula sed vel nulla. Integer sed ipsum semper, auctor massa eget, viverra justo. Nullam mattis suscipit lorem vel mattis. Morbi non aliquet nunc. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
    </p>
    <p>
      Pellentesque dapibus sapien quis congue porta. Maecenas faucibus ex nisi, in varius risus imperdiet ac. Aliquam tristique egestas ligula, sed vestibulum lacus mollis vel. Nunc non ante ut quam placerat suscipit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
      adipiscing elit. In a viverra augue, a dignissim justo. Aliquam volutpat nibh ut tellus interdum suscipit. Praesent mi sem, mollis in libero vel, pretium accumsan ex. Nullam gravida diam quis semper faucibus. Nullam cursus felis dolor, sed egestas
      ex lobortis et. Vivamus at maximus felis, vel posuere purus. Quisque pellentesque risus nec posuere suscipit. Aliquam eleifend tempus ante, vel vehicula nunc facilisis quis. Mauris lacinia, felis at ultrices luctus, lacus nisl molestie neque, et
      varius urna velit at massa. Nulla facilisi.
    </p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not absolutely sure what you're trying to do but try adding this to your css and see if it fixes it.

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. The border on div1 and div2 is just to show the height of the div. Feel free to remove it ;)

```css
#container {
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
}   

.div1 {
      height: 200px;
      position: relative;
      border: 2px solid yellow;
    }

.div2 {
      overflow-y: auto;
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
      border: 2px solid red;
    }
```

```html
    <div id='container' style="height:100%">
      <div class='div1'>
        div1 content
      </div>
      <div class='div2'>
        div2 content
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: still I am getting the browser default vertical scrolling. And also scroll bar for div2 is not so responsive.

Comment: I didn't see any code that you try to replace the default scroll. Could you update the script with the complete code, please?

Comment: currently I don't have code for fixing the default window vertical scroll. That is my part of question.